# How To Get Values Out of An Array Inside Of A Class

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, class

I have a form that is passing array values to *create_parts.php*, then I am trying to pass those values to the parts class to insert into the database. At this point I am just lost... The form passes to *create_parts.php*, I  can echo the results of the of the array. However in my class I cant get any values thus,  my insert into the database is just a bunch of `NULL`.

```
<?php
include_once '../config/database.php';
include_once '../objects/parts_object.php';

$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

$parts= new parts($db);

    $parts->est_part_idArr=$_POST['est_part_id'];
    $parts->part_qtyArr=$_POST['part_qty'];
    $parts->part_numArr=$_POST['part_num'];
    $parts->part_discArr=$_POST['part_disc'];
    $parts->part_costArr=$_POST['part_cost'];

$parts->create();
```

I am able to to echo out the results here and get

```
{"est_part_idArr":["123","124"],"part_qtyArr":["4","6"],"part_numArr":
["2334","3344"],"part_discArr":["part","parts"],"part_costArr":["56","33"]
```

and echo the $stmt

`{"queryString":"INSERT INTO \r\n partsT\r\n SET \r\n est_part_id=:est_part_id, part_qty=:part_qty, part_num=:part_num, part_disc=:part_disc, part_cost=:part_cost"}`

However in *part_object.php* I cant get anything to work. I can it to insert to the database but it is all `NULL`.

```
class parts{

private $conn;
private $table_name = "partsT";

public $est_part_idArr;
public $part_qtyArr;
public $part_numArr;
public $part_discArr;
public $part_costArr;

public function __construct($db){
$this->conn = $db; }

function create(){

  $query = "INSERT INTO 
                " . $this->table_name . "
            SET 
               est_part_id=:est_part_id, part_qty=:part_qty, part_num=:part_num, part_disc=:part_disc, part_cost=:part_cost";

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

if(!empty($this->$est_part_idArr)){
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->$est_part_idArr); $i++) {
        if(!empty($this->$est_part_idArr[$i])){
            $est_part_id = $this->$est_part_idArr[$i];
            $part_qty = $this->$part_qtyArr[$i];
            $part_num = $this->$part_numArr[$i];
            $part_disc = $this->$part_discArr[$i];
            $part_cost = $this->$part_costArr[$i];
        $stmt->execute(array(
        ':est_part_id'  => $est_part_id,
        ':part_qty'     => $part_qty,
        ':part_num'     => $part_num,
        ':part_disc'    => $part_disc,
        ':part_cost'    => $part_cost));

        }
    }
 }

    $this->est_part_idArr=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->est_part_idArr));
    $this->part_qtyArr=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->part_qtyArr));
    $this->part_numArr=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->part_numArr));
    $this->part_discArr=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->part_discArr));
    $this->part_costArr=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->part_costArr));


    $stmt->bindParam(":est_part_id", $this->est_part_idArr[0]);
    $stmt->bindParam(":part_qty", $this->part_qtyArr[0]);
    $stmt->bindParam(":part_num", $this->part_numArr[0]);
    $stmt->bindParam(":part_disc", $this->part_discArr[0]);
    $stmt->bindParam(":part_cost", $this->part_costArr[0]);

if($stmt->execute()){
        return true;

    }else{
        return false;
    }
        }
```

At this point I know

```
public $est_part_idArr;
public $part_qtyArr;
public $part_numArr;
public $part_discArr;
public $part_costArr;
```

is wrong I just cant get anything to work.

Comment: Updated the code to reflect on the suggestions. I tried every permutation I could think of and still getting NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing some `$this` in front of your variables to access your public class members. Let us take this line for example:

```
$est_part_id = $est_part_idArr[$i];
```

which in my opinion should look like this:

```
$est_part_id = $this->est_part_idArr[$i];
```

On the other hand when you bind your parameters some lines down the code you're using something like this:

```
$stmt->bindParam(":est_part_id", $this->est_part_id);
```

Which I believe should be

```
$stmt->bindParam(":est_part_id", $this->est_part_idArr);
```

or

```
$stmt->bindParam(":est_part_id", $this->est_part_idArr[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much this lead me to the solution.  Very much appreciated!